# calculation of lapsed time between two entry

Tags: sql

I have table which records staff's work log. The table columns as staffid,orderid,Startingtime,endingtime etc.I know how to find the difference between two time ie starting and ending time. But I need to know how many minutes lapsing a worker to start another work.
staffid  workid  Startingtime  endingtime  timetaken
100       10222    11.30 pm      11.50 pm     20
100       20122    11.55 pm      01.55 pm     120
Here i need to calculate how many minutes staff lapsed between two work.(here 5 minutes 11.50pm and 11.55 pm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below query query for the desired result. 
Note : The query will work on a daily basis against all the staffs.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CalcTimeDiff
 (Staffid INT
  ,Orderid INT
  ,Startingtime DateTime
  ,Endingtime Datetime
 )
 GO


 INSERT INTO dbo.CalcTimeDiff
 SELECT '1','1','2016-08-21 11:30:00.000','2016-08-21 11:50:00.000'
 UNION
 SELECT '1','2','2016-08-21 11:55:00.000','2016-08-21 13:55:00.000'
 GO
```

Below query will give you the lapsed time in minute.

```
SELECT StaffiD,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(Startingtime),MAX(endingtime))-SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Startingtime,endingtime)) LapsedTime
FROM dbo.CalcTimeDiff
GROUP BY StaffiD,convert(date,Startingtime)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here worklog is name of table and instead of '11.50 AM', i stored result as '11:50 AM'. I guess it solves your issue

```
DECLARE @DIFFERENCE INT,@TIME1 VARCHAR(10),@TIME2 VARCHAR(10),@ID INT
DECLARE @TEMP_DATE TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),STAFFID INT, WORKID INT, 
STARTINGTIME VARCHAR(10), ENDINGTIME VARCHAR(10), TIMETAKEN INT)
INSERT INTO @TEMP_DATE SELECT * FROM WORKLOG

DECLARE C CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID FROM @TEMP_DATE
OPEN C
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
IF (@ID != (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM WORKLOG))
BEGIN

SET @TIME1=(SELECT STARTINGTIME FROM @TEMP_DATE WHERE ID=@ID)
SET @TIME2=(SELECT STARTINGTIME FROM @TEMP_DATE WHERE ID=(@ID+1))
set @DIFFERENCE=(SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,cast(@TIME1 as time), cast(@TIME2 as time)))
set @TIME1=(select cast(WORKID as varchar(20)) from @TEMP_DATE where id=@id)
set @TIME2=(select cast(WORKID as varchar(20)) from @TEMP_DATE where id=(@id+1))
PRINT 'Time difference between workid ('+@TIME1+' and '+@TIME2+') is    =>  '+cast(@DIFFERENCE as varchar(20))
END
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @ID
END
CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C
```